# Remove "Save & Send" from File menu in Excel 2010 using custom XML

Tags: xml, excel, excel-2010, ribbon-control

Could someone please help me modify the following XML code (Office 2007) so that it works in Office 2010?  I've included my XML from Office 2007 below:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
<ribbon>
    <officeMenu>
        <menu idMso="FileSendMenu" enabled="false"/>
        <menu idMso="FileEmailAsPdfEmailAttachment" enabled="false"/>
        <menu idMso="FileEmailAsXpsEmailAttachment" enabled="false"/>
        <menu idMso="FileSendAsAttachment" enabled="false"/>
    </officeMenu>
</ribbon>
```

I canNOT figure out why my schema isn't working.  It doesn't help that I know nothing about XML and I'm just kind of fumbling around in the dark here.  My goal is to ideally remove (or at least disable) the "Save & Send" menu item under the File menu in Excel 2010.  I am not finding any documentation on the XML structure for Office 2010, which seems to have changed significantly from Office 2007.

Answer (score 3):

So of course right after I asked this question I found the solution.  Here's the format to remove the various items under the File ribbon (what is now apparently called backstage in Office 2010):

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
<backstage>
    <button idMso="FileSave" visible="false"/>
    <button idMso="FileSaveAs" visible="false"/>
    <button idMso="FileOpen" visible="false"/>
    <button idMso="FileClose" visible="false"/>
    <button idMso="ApplicationOptionsDialog" visible="false"/>
    <button idMso="FileExit" visible="false"/>
    <tab idMso="TabInfo" visible="false"/>
    <tab idMso="TabRecent" visible="false"/>
    <tab idMso="TabNew" visible="false"/>
    <tab idMso="TabPrint" visible="false"/>
    <tab idMso="TabShare" visible="false"/>
    <tab idMso="TabHelp" visible="false"/>
    </backstage>
</customUI>
```

This will remove every option under the File menu.  You can obviously selectively remove/show the elements you want to.

Comment: Do you have a link to a comprehensive list of all tab, buttons, commands that we can influence in Office 2010 ?

Comment: where should you copy/paste this xml ?

Comment: Hubert, Download "Custom UI Editor For Microsoft Office" open the the file using the software then after proceed to insert menu - > choose the enviroment in 2007 or 2010; if 2007 then office/2009/07/ should be changed to office/2006/01/ and some components might change; for change in Control name refer to the http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6627