# How do you disable "Save and send" in Excel 2010 (in the File ribbon (called backstage in Office 2010)?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, ribbon, ribbonx

I have the following VBA marco running in Excel 2003, it blocks the Save, Save as, Save Workspace, Send To 
menus but I now need to do the same but for Excel 2010 ?

> Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("File").Controls("Save As...").Enabled = False
>
>
> Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("File").Controls("Save").Enabled = False
>
>
>
> Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("File").Controls("Save Workspace...").Enabled = False
>
>
>
> Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("File").Controls("Send To").Enabled = False
>
>
>
> Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("Format").Controls("Sheet").Enabled = False

There is a 'new menu' in Excel 2010 called "Save and send" (under the File ribbon) that I would like to also disable... How do you do this ? I’m searching for the equivalent to a line like this one:

`'Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("File").Controls("Save & Send").Enabled = False`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you try prevent a save, would not be better to handle "Workbook_BeforeSave" event?

Comment: See [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697013/remove-save-send-from-file-menu-in-excel-2010-using-custom-xml) for an answer.

Comment: +1 @SkipIntro this is a job for Ribbon/XML editing. The linked answer may need some more detail for OP to implement. I believe this is the `FileSendAsAttachment` button control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Ribbon UI example/documentation from Microsoft, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691832(v=office.14).aspx).  They will recommend you use the [CustomUI Editor](http://openxmldeveloper.org/archive/2009/08/06/7293.aspx).

Open your file (which must be an Excel 2007+ file extension like XLSX, XLSM, XLAM, etc) in the CustomUI Editor.  Then use this XML in the editor:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
<backstage>
    <tab idMso="TabShare" visible="false" enabled="false">
    </tab>
</backstage>
</customUI>
```

Save the file, and close the CustomUI Editor.

Then, open your file.  Go to the File/Backstage view and you should see that the `Save and Send` tab has been removed:

[image: screenshot of disabled TabShare]

**Note:** This has disabled the entire "Save & Send" tab from the backstage view. It should be possible using XML to fine-tune this, i.e., to enable the tab, but disable specific controls therein (e.g., maybe you only want to disable `Send as Attachment` but you want to leave the other options enabled, etc.) but I haven't quite worked out the XML hierarchy to disable *only* the specific `Send As Attachment` control.

Hope this helps!

**Update from Comments**

1) The user will find "normal" functionality when this file is closed, or when another file is Active.  The UI customization only applies to the file which contains the Custom UI XML parts, so if you have multiple files open, only this file will be affected by the disabled `Save & Send` tab.

2) Unfortunately, this is *not* compatible with Excel 2003 or prior. The CustomUI/XML is not a part of the legacy XLS files, and as such, cannot be implemented in these versions.  For 2003/prior versions of Excel, you will have to use the legacy `CommandBars` which can be controlled through VBA.  It is relatively easy to put some VBA code that will check which version of Excel, and run a subroutine to disable certain `CommandBar`/Controls only if the user is in 2003 or prior versions.

If you try to save this down to an XLS file, you will receive a warning, indicating that this feature is incompatible with the file type:

[image: CustomUI XML not compatible with XLS files]

Additionally, you cannot open an XLS file in the CustomUI Editor.

Comment: First, thanks a lot for your answer. 2 quick questions before I validate the answer: 1. Will this be linked to the excel file in question and not to the whole Excel ? In other words, will the user find back its 'normal' config once he closes my xls file ? 2. will this excel file still work for my users that are still using Excel 2003 ? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @Hubert I am going to update my answer to address both of your questions.

Comment: @David Zemens How can I disable Save As? I didn't find a working solution.

Comment: You should ask a new question instead of hijacking the comments on this question. Cheers 

Answer (score 3):

I have tried commands listed below and these are disabling the save and send menu in `Excel 2010`:

```
Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("File").Controls("Send To").Enabled = False
Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("File").Controls("Save & Send").Enabled = False
```

Comment: +1 for this late answer, but it would be worth noting that this method disables these controls for **ALL** Excel files, in-fact disables it for the entire Excel Application unless and until you re-enable them.

Answer (score -2):

This commands worked for me

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
<commands>
    <command idMso="TabShare" enabled="false"/>
</commands> 
</customUI>
```