# VBA when user clicks Send as Attachement

Tags: vba, excel, ribbonx

My company has an issue with Outlook when it is triggered to open by Excel that causes Outlook to hang indefinitely when loading (an issue which cannot be easily fixed). We have a few workbooks with custom ribbons where we now check that Outlook is open first before allowing the user to send via email. The problem is that this doesn't account for users that still use the File > Save & Send > Send as Attachment.

I would like to know if anybody knows about a process by which I can add on a routine to the existing button that we could save as an Excel Add In on everyone's Excel that checks first if Outlook is open? I have the Outlook check written so I'm just needing help with finding a way to run it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could disable Send as Attachment.

I wouldn't know what is important so I won't copy parts here.

[How do you disable “Save and send” in Excel 2010 (in the File ribbon (called backstage in Office 2010)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722987/how-do-you-disable-save-and-send-in-excel-2010-in-the-file-ribbon-called-bac)

[Disable the Send button in the Office Menu](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c1e87a81-3498-4953-8b40-064864474180/disable-the-send-button-in-the-office-menu)

Answer (score 0):

You may consider repurposing the ribbon controls. See [Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462633(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.

Unfortunately the Backstage UI doesn't allow to repurpose controls from the XML markup. You may consider hiding the built-in UI and rebuilding it fully with custom commands. Thus, you will be able to handle the commands on your own. You can read more about that in the [Introduction to the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691833%28v=office.14%29.aspx) article. Also see the [Customizing the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee815851(v=office.14).aspx) article.