# Excel 2010-2019 - Remove File menu items and add new Tabs in CustomUI

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I would like to have CustomUI tabs and also remove File menu items in my xlsm file.
I have mu customUI tabs, however, while following example given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697013/remove-save-send-from-file-menu-in-excel-2010-using-custom-xml) to remove File menu items my custom tabs disappear and also file menu items are not being disabled.

So, when I place the following xml in Custom UI Editor for Microsoft Office File menu items are disabled, however, my custom tabs do not appear any more:

```
    <backstage>
    <button idMso="FileSave" visible="false"/>
    <button idMso="FileSaveAs" visible="false"/>
    <button idMso="FileOpen" visible="false"/>
    <button idMso="FileClose" visible="false"/>
    <button idMso="ApplicationOptionsDialog" visible="false"/>
    <button idMso="FileExit" visible="false"/>
    <tab idMso="TabInfo" visible="false"/>
    <tab idMso="TabRecent" visible="false"/>
    <tab idMso="TabNew" visible="false"/>
    <tab idMso="TabPrint" visible="false"/>
    <tab idMso="TabShare" visible="false"/>
    <tab idMso="TabHelp" visible="false"/>
 </backstage>
```

Here's my xml structure :

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
<backstage>
    <button idMso="FileSave" visible="false"/>
    <button idMso="FileSaveAs" visible="false"/>
    <button idMso="FileOpen" visible="false"/>
    <button idMso="FileClose" visible="false"/>
    <button idMso="ApplicationOptionsDialog" visible="false"/>
    <button idMso="FileExit" visible="false"/>
    <tab idMso="TabInfo" visible="false"/>
    <tab idMso="TabRecent" visible="false"/>
    <tab idMso="TabNew" visible="false"/>
    <tab idMso="TabPrint" visible="false"/>
    <tab idMso="TabShare" visible="false"/>
    <tab idMso="TabHelp" visible="false"/>
 </backstage>

    <ribbon startFromScratch="true">
        <tabs>
            <tab id="1" label="1" insertAfterMso="TabHome">
                
                <group id="customGroupMain" label="Main">
                    ------------------
                </group>


        
            </tab>
            <tab id="2" label="2" >

                <group id="customGroupResults" label="Results">
                    --------------
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Maybe am placing the "backstage" in the wrong place? Can't figure it out.
Thanks for advise!

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by adding "backstage" xml code after `</ribbon>`